# How get sets of integer which appear in at least K or more than K sub-array(s) from array. Each set must have exactly L elements ?

Tags: arrays

I want to write program with input an array which contains N sub-array(s). Each sub-array is an array of integers which has M element(s). N and M can be very large (e.g. 1.000.000). It assume that the arrays can be stored in physical memory. The program would output: All sets of integers which appear in at least K or more than K sub-array(s). Each set must have exactly L elements.

Ex:
   Input:

```
    N = 5
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    {1, 3, 2}
    {1, 4, 3, 2, 9}
    {2, 3, 4, 7, 9}
    {3, 4, 5, 9, 10}
```

Output:

```
    1. In case K = 3, L = 2
    {1, 2}
    {1, 3}
    {2, 3}
    {2, 4}
    {3, 4}
    {3, 9}
    {4, 9}

    2. In case K = 3, L = 3
    {1, 2, 3}
    {2, 3, 4}
```

How can I do ?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, we are here to help you fix your code, not to write everything from scratch for you. What have you tried already? It might also help to tag the language you're using in your question.

Comment: I have wrote a function to get each element from array, but I don't know way to combine each element in array to assign to new array which have L elements

Comment: please edit your question and add the relevant code.